# Метод sys.debug(string)

Tags: node.js

`sys.debug(string)`. В описании этого метода написано, что он блокирует процесс и выводит строку. Как понимать "блокирует процесс"? То есть останавливает весь скрипт или что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> он блокирует процесс и выводит строку

[[@Zow](/users/4425/zow)](/users/4425/zow), это значит, что данная операция ввода/вывода *блокирующая*, т.е. выполняется *синхронно*. Пока не завершится вывод текстового сообщения, выполнение программы будет приостановлено.

Это немаловажная оговорка в документации, т.к. идеология node.js основана на *асинхронных* (неблокирующих) вызовах. Работа, с файлами, например, реализована в обоих вариантах (сравните синхронный `fs.readSync(...)` и асинхронный `fs.read(...)`), причем *асинхронный* вариант является предпочтительным.